# Finding the single possibility

Tags: probability

If I have `x + y = 4` and I know x and y can either be 1 and 3 or 2 and 2, is there any way to tell which combination it is?

Comment: This isn't clear at all.  If you know that $(x,y)$ can be either $(1,3)$ or $(2,2)$ and you have no other information, why do think there is a way of choosing between the two possibilities?

Comment: From that information alone, no.  There are even more possibilities than that if you allow negative integers such as $x=-50,y=54$ and so on, and even more still if you allow any rational or real results.  Two unknowns and one linear equation relating them is never enough information to uniquely determine anything.

Comment: You already answered your own question by saying that "I know x and y can either be 1 and 3 or 2 and 2".

Answer (score 2):

No. You require an additional constraint in order to solve for $(x,y)$ uniquely.

In general, systems of linear equations with $n$ degrees of freedom (i.e. variables) require $n$ equations for a unique solution.

If the number of degrees of freedom exceeds the number of equations, as in this case, we call that an underdetermined system. The result is that there either exists no solution or there exists infinitely many solutions. Your example has infinitely many solutions if we include the negative integers.

Comment: Replace "polynomial equations" with "linear equations", otherwise you'll end up with things like $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ which clearly has only one solution over the reals.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks. Done!